# have much in common/have many in common

Tags: word-usage

I am confused about "have much in common" and "have many in common".

I have searched and I know the phrase "have something in common".

If I want to convey that between Jack and I both like many stuffs and have the same tastes,such as movies,songs,games and so on.

How should I say it correctly,by this way?

```
Jack and I have much in common so we become good friends
Jack and I have many in common so we become good friends
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While 'much' can go without any direct reference, 'many' does require it.

> There's nothing **much** to do

is okay.

But...

> There are many **things** to do

required 'things' to follow many.

Thus, if you use 'many', you may need to add 'what' in your sentence. Maybe, many 'things', 'hobbies' or the like.

One of the references I could find (quickly) is...

> Warriors, Stanley Cup finalist Tampa Bay **have much in common.**

You may call those all as 'things'. It's fine.

> Jack and I have **many things in common** so we become good friends.

Comment: Cool. My friend told  me I should use 'much ',but he didn't tell me why. You did it. Thanks.